# mat-tab lazy load tab only once

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using Angular Material mat-tab and it is set to lazy load the tabs content.

Since the first tab is loaded by default I have set second tab to load lazily.

I see that when I navigates between the tabs repeatedly, the second tab's content is loading freshly every time. I have a Web API call to get data and show in the tab content.

So I want to avoid the Web API call every time the tab is selected. How can I achieve that?

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <!--Roles Tab-->
  <mat-tab class="tabLabel" label="Roles">
    <app-roles></app-roles>
  </mat-tab>
  <!--Admins Tab-->
  <mat-tab class="tabLabel" label="Admins">
    <!-- Lazy load below component -->
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <app-admins></app-admins>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the event `selectedIndexChange` on mat-tab-group and put your content in a div with ngIf,like this:

```html
<mat-tab-group (selectedIndexChange)="tabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Today">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
   <mat-tab label="Yesterday">
     <div *ngIf="yesterDayTabShow">
    <hello name="Test"></hello>
     </div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

See the link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tu7jsg

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: The second tab isn't loading with Lazy Loading. matTabContent is applied to the first tab in this solution. If you add this line: <input type="text"> at app.component.html inside both two: <mat-tab> the first tab deletes the content because it reloads on click. I know this is the solution that he's looking for, but I'm need lazy loading all tabs just at first click (to keep content inside all tabs after lazy loading for the first time.

Comment: I know this is old, but the above helped me.  @fabio984 could you make the starting index -1 such that no div's are shown? Then only an index is set on click (change) and the correct one shows...

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create componenet as a lazy loading wrapper

```
<ng-container></ng-container>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="contentTemplate" *ngIf="loadContent"></ng-container>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cmp-lazy-load-container',
  templateUrl: './lazy-load-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lazy-load-container.component.css'],
})
export class LazyLoadContainerComponent implements AfterContentChecked {
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  @ContentChild('body', { static: true })
  contentTemplate: TemplateRef<ElementRef>;

  loadContent: boolean;
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    if (this.elRef.nativeElement.offsetParent) this.loadContent = true;
  }
}
```

To use it:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> 
    <cmp-lazy-load-container>
      <ng-template #body>
       What ever you wish to be lazy loaded here...
      </ng-template>
    </cmp-lazy-load-container>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> 
    <cmp-lazy-load-container>
      <ng-template #body>
       What ever else you wish to be lazy loaded here...
      </ng-template>
    </cmp-lazy-load-container>  
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The cmp-lazy-load-container only initializes the content in the #body template once when it becomes visible.

And this lazy component can be used in other places too.

A working sample here: https://angular-ivy-avqx3u.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Declare empty variable in your ts file

***eg.*** `let data = undefined;`

**2.** Store your Api Data in declared variable

`data = Response`

**3.** Call API only if `data === undefined`

I hope this will work for u.

Comment: Hi Swapnil,Thanks for your suggestion.But it is not working for me. The data is undefined every time I click on the tab. Its not maintaining the data value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Steven.Xi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3855789/steven-xi)'s idea I've implemented it with standalone directive:

```
import {
  Directive,
  InjectionToken,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef,
} from '@angular/core'

export const LAZY_CONTENT = new InjectionToken<LazyContent>('LazyContent')

/**
 * Use 'lazyContent' directive to load template content only when its parent visible.
 * Based on the Steven.Xi's idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974290/4180933
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[LazyContent]',
  providers: [{ provide: LAZY_CONTENT, useExisting: LazyContent }],
  standalone: true,
})
export class LazyContent {
  private _isCreated = false
  private get _isVisible(): boolean {
    return !!this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement
      ?.offsetParent
  }

  constructor(
    public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // embed template if parent element is visible
    if (!this._isCreated && this._isVisible) {
      this._isCreated = true
      setTimeout(() => this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef))
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First"> 
    <ng-template lazyContent>
      What ever you wish to be lazy loaded here...
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> 
    <ng-template lazyContent>
      What ever you wish to be lazy loaded here...
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```